# Add view to the windows?

Tags: ios

Ususally we add a view to the window using

```
[self.window addSubview:self.rootViewController.view];
```

I am wondering how many subviews can be added to self.window?

Also, I think we don't use create a class for UIView, rather we will rely on viewcontroller to create view , is that right?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a limit to the number of subviews, though you would usually only add one subview to the window and then add other subviews to that view.

You can create subclasses of `UIView`, indeed there are many subviews provided by `UIKit`. The important part is the distinction between the responsibility of the classes you create and use. Using MVC means you have a view controller which maintains all of the control logic and updates the view. You also have a (subclass of) `UIView` which hosts the visual representation of whatever content is in your data model.